# how to use echo with find in bash?

Tags: bash, find

I have 10 files. I can list them with `find . -type f` and what I am trying to achieve is sending a message to all 10 files after finding them with find command.

What I have tried, `find . -type f -exec echo "This file found" >> {} \;`

May be logically I am right but its not working. Is there any way I can achieve with using `find` and `echo` only ?

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The shell redirection, `>>` is being done at first, a file named `{}` is being created before even the `find` starts and the strings (the number of files are in there) are being written to the file `{}`.

You need:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'echo "This file found" >>"$1"' _ {} \;
```

Comment: You again , oh man. How do you know these many things. :P dont say learning.

Comment: @Raja Perfect timing i guess :P

Comment: Yes Heemayl. Thank you again. :)

Comment: I don't get the purpose of `_`. Why not using `$0` instead of `$1` without the character `_`?

Comment: Technically, the first argument to `bash -c "..."` is the value used for `$0`, not the first positional argument. You *could* use `bash -c "echo "This file found" >> "$0"' {}`, but that's arguably abusing the `$0` parameter. (I'm not aware of any problems that could occur if you did, though.)

Comment: @chepner I'm not convinced with your explanation... at least this is not what man pages say. I ask a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38866883/2214695)