# How to delete the same files in the two directories with comparison in linux?

Tags: bash, find, cmp

I want to delete the same files in two directories. 
Both have so many files with the same name. If two files are same I want to delete in the first directory.
I am not sure whether linux shell is better choice or python would be better.

1. `$HOME/bin`
2. `$HOME/cin`

In some search, there is an close answer for comparison.

```
find cin -type f -exec cmp '{}' "bin/{}" \;
```

But this is not working because the first output of `find`, {} contains "cin/" directory name such as "cin/file1". So the second "bin/{}" has "bin/cin/file1". Then comparison error occurs

```
cmp: bin/cin/file1: No such file or directory
```

how to compare cin/file1 and bin/file1?

Comment: And I have tried -printf "%f\n" or basename {}. They just affect the standard output for "find" but it looks they does not go into {}.

Comment: You might run it from `cin` folder (`find . -type ...`) and use `../bin/{}` instead. This should solve `bin/cin/` path problems.

Comment: Have you considered using `fdupes`?

Comment: @hradecek, that is right! It works if it runs inside the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `find` command:

```
find cin -type f -exec bash -c 'f="${1#cin/}"; cmp "cin/$f" "bin/$f"' _ {} \;
```

It executes the command inside `bash -c` for all regular files in `cin` directory.

The upper directory is removed by the bash*ism* `${1#...}` and the variable `f` is set to relative path.

Comment: Would you explain some more about bashism or refer to more webpage? and what is the role of underbar, '_'?

Comment: You can look at `man --pager='less -p \\${parameter#' bash` for your first question and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38866883/how-to-use-positional-parameters-with-bash-c-command) for your second one.