# How to handle single quote/ apostrophe and space together in linux cat command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, operating-system, cat

I have a file named `test's file.txt` inside `test's dir` directory.
So the file-path becomes `test's dir/test's file.txt`.
I want to cat the content of the file but since the file contains an apostrophe and a space it is giving me hard time achieving that.
I have tried several commands including

1. `sh -c "cat 'test's dir/test's file.txt'"`
2. `sh -c 'cat "test's dir/test's file.txt"'`
3. `sh -c "cat '"'"'test's dir/test's file.txt'"'"'"`
4. `sh -c 'cat "test\'s\ dir/test\'s\ file.txt"'`
   and many more ...
   But none of them is working.

Some help would be really appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Is there a particular reason, why you want to do a `sh -c` to do this, instead of invoking `cat` directly?

Comment: Using `sh -c` requires adding a second layer of quoting/escaping, which complicates the syntax quite a lot. To run the `cat` command directly (without `sh -c`), you could just use double-quotes: `cat "test's dir/test's file.txt"`.

Comment: See [How to have simple and double quotes in a scripted ssh command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45308395/4154375) for good information about quoting commands for later evaluation (by `ssh`, `eval`, `sh -c`, ...).

Comment: Apart from an academic exercise, is there a good reason to have file or directory names with either spaces or quotes (single or double — or back) in the name?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I mostly use macOS, so spaces (and other funny characters) in filenames are just facts of life. Any script or program that can't handle them is going to cause trouble. (More generally, most GUI users aren't aware of what characters are hard to deal with at the command line, so you can't expect them to avoid such characters.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please try:

```
sh -c "cat 'test'\''s dir/test'\''s file.txt'"
```

As for the pathname part, it is a concatenation of:

```
'test'
\'
's dir/test'
\'
's file.txt'
```

**[Edit]**
If you want to execute the shell command in `python`, would you please try:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess

path="test's dir/test's file.txt"
subprocess.run(['cat', path])
```

or immediately:

```
subprocess.run(['cat', "test's dir/test's file.txt"])
```

As the `subprocess.run()` function takes the command as a list,
not a single string (possible with `shell=True` option), we do not have
to worry about the extra quoting around the command.

Please note `subprocess.run()` is supported by Python 3.5 or newer.

Comment: This is great @tshiono, this solution looks perfect for my problem. Thanks a lot, appreciate the quick help :)

Comment: Is there any python library that handles such cases?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. If you think your problem is solved, I'd be pleased if you can accept the answer by clicking the check mark beside the answer

Comment: As for python, do you want to invoke shell command from within the python script?

Comment: Yes, I'll be executing this command via shell executer. But I wanted to check if there's a python library which can re-format the command to handle such cases (quotes, spaces)

Comment: I've updated my answer with a python version. If it is not what you expect, please elaborate about what you want to execute and the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use here-doc:

```sh
sh -s <<-'EOF'
cat "test's dir/test's file.txt"
EOF
```

Comment: Hi @anubhava, yes this worked for me. Thanks a lot for the quick help. But I was looking for a one line solution for this with limited changes. But this is good stuff, learned something new today.

Answer (score 0):

This option avoids the need for two levels of quoting:

```
sh -c 'cat -- "$0"' "test's dir/test's file.txt"
```

See [How to use positional parameters with "bash -c" command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38866883/4154375).  (It applies to `sh -c` too.)